# How to setup Mac Studio to host multiple Jenkins agents

Tags: jenkins, virtualization, macos, vmware

I am responsible for the administration of a Jenkins and its infrastructure. We have several software projects that rely on specific Xcode versions and with that rely on specific macOS versions. Now I have a quite powerful Mac Studio with 24C CPU 60C GPU 128GB RAM 4TB HDD. Usually I would setup several VMWare Fusion VMs running different macOS versions and connect those VMs as agents to my Jenkins controller.

Now I was wondering whether this is the best setup performance wise. I also saw that macOS itself offers some kind of VM: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/installing_macos_on_a_virtual_machine but it was hard for me to understand the concept.

So to sum up things, I have two questions:

1.) When building with Xcode, can I have more than one build processor on a macOS agent or is this prone to cause errors with the Xcode cache or something similar?

2.) Is VMWare Fusion still the best option to virtualize macOS on macOS, especially when the goal is to have an older macOS running within the guest?

Thanks, open to suggestions.